# Delete a file from a related list by non-owner

Tags: related-list, files, delete

I have a record with a file in a related list. I want to allow a non-owner to delete that file. Since you can't add a custom button to that list and non-owners can't delete a file how can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom visualforce/aura/lwc that has a controller ran without sharing(system mode)